# Error al querer utilizar el carácter de búsqueda en postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Estoy intentando hacer un procedimiento almacenado que al insertar un parametro este lo busque mediante un select postgresql, pero el error que me da es el siguiente "no existe la columna «'»" . Este es mi codigo:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION carros(modelo_carro) RETURNS TEXT AS 
 $$
 BEGIN 
     SELECT modelo, nombre, marca FROM carros WHERE "'"||modelo_carro||"%'" 
         LIKE modelo

 END;
 $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta indicar la columna en el where que vas a comparar además del operador de comparación, que viendo cómo creas la cadena a comparar supongo que querrás usar like:

```
SELECT modelo, nombre, marca FROM carros WHERE COLUMNA like '''' || modelo_carro|| '%'''
```

En tu caso supongo que sería:

```
SELECT modelo, nombre, marca FROM carros WHERE modelo like '''' || modelo_carro|| '%'''
```

Ojo que lo que creo que quieres hacer es:

```
SELECT modelo, nombre, marca FROM carros WHERE modelo like modelo_carro || '%'
```

Ya que modelo de carro debería ser una cadena de por sí.

Puedes verlo funcionar en:

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d5193/2)

Comment: Se la especifique, pero me sigue marcando el error en la concatenación: "no existe la columna «'»"

Comment: Para escapar las comillas se coloca la misma dos veces dentro de la cadena, ejemplo: 'hola ''como'' estas??', edité la respuesta

Comment: te agregué un fiddle para que lo puedas ver funcionando

Comment: Gracias me funciono la ultima :)